# Flask-WTF: passing object to Ninja2-template => no filter named 'tojason’

Tags: javascript, jinja2, flask-wtforms

From one of my Flask routes I pass an object (selectedStek) to a Jinja2 template

```
from flask import (Blueprint, current_app, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, url_for)
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from flask_uploads import IMAGES, UploadSet, configure_uploads

from . import db
from .forms import createStekForm
from .models import Stek, Stektype

stekken = Blueprint("stekken", __name__)


@stekken.route("/stek_modify/<stekId>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required

def stek_modify(stekId):

    form = createStekForm()
    selectedStek = Stek.query.filter_by(id = int(stekId)).first() 

    return render_template('stek_modify.html', form=form, stek=selectedStek"])
```

Which I then want to use in a javascript with tojason

```
{% block content %}

<h3>{{stek.place}} </h3>

{% endblock %}


{% block scripts %}

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

    console.log( "ready!" );

    varKo = ({{stek.place|tojson }});

    console.log(varKo);
    
    }); // document.readyFunction

</script>
    
{% endblock %}
```

This code returns an error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'tojason'".

I just can't figure out what's wrong.
Probably something simple but I need some help to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It is tojason or tojson?
If it is tojson, could you try with  updated jinja2 like 2.9.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You're absolutely right and I feel a bit stupid. It must of course be tojson and then the code worked right away. I've been working on it for too long, which made me kind of blind and I couldn't figure it out myself....

Comment: Yes I understand. Hope now your code is working :)